# Convert TS with closed captions into MKV/MP4 with sub title

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a TS file ( with US closed captions ) into MKV ( or MP4 ).  Currently I am doing using a three step approach.

Step-1 : Extract the subtitle in srt format.

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "movie=test.ts[out0+subcc]" -map s output.srt

Step-2 :  Transcode the TS into MKV

ffmpeg i test.ts -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy out.mkv

Step-3 :  Add subtitle back to out.mkv

ffmpeg -i out.mkv -i output.srt -acodec copy -vcodec copy -scodec copy final.mkv.

I believe all these three steps can be combined in a single ffmeg command. Is there any way to do this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
ffmpeg -i test.ts -f lavfi -i "movie=test.ts[out0+subcc]" -map 0 -map 1:s -c:a copy -c:s srt final.mkv
```

Hopefully, the timestamps for the subtitles will be in sync :)

Comment: Thanks.  I believe I need to  add -c:v libx264 also. Correct?

Comment: For assurance, sure. But it's the default video codec for MKV/MP4, so not strictly needed.